# background task not waiting for file writes

Tags: c#

I have a long-running background task which is just a while loop constantly iterating over a `BlockingCollection` to log messages to a file. At first i used a `foreach` loop which would create a `streamwriter` and write the line asynchronously.

```
    public static BlockingCollection<LogMessage> LogMessages = new BlockingCollection<LogMessage>();
    private static async void RunTask()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var allMessages = LogMessages.GetConsumingEnumerable();
            foreach (var message in allMessages)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(File.Open(DebugPath, FileMode.Append)))
                {
                    await sr.WriteLineAsync(message.Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above worked well, but it didn't seem like the best way utilize the `streamwriter`, so I tried switching the `foreach` and `using` statements. This caused the debug file to be created, but the file would stay at 0kb and never save. Also I couldn't open the file because it was in use while the application was open.

```
        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(File.Open(DebugPath, FileMode.Append)))
        {
            foreach (var message in allMessages)     
            {
                // I suspect it's not waiting for this to finish.
                await sr.WriteLineAsync(message.Text);
            }
        }
```

Is this the expected behavior of the background task? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I would just use append or write all text.

Comment: Also I would try to create new files every so often....like for example put the Year_Month_Day_Hour on the file name... that way there is a new file per hour... or something like that.

Comment: You may need to flush the via [StreamWriter.Flush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.flush?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamWriter_Flush).  Though, I agree append is probably a better approach if you care about seeing the log while it's running.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I just changed it to remove the foreach and streamwriter, now it's a simple `File.AppendAllLines(DebugPath, debugMessages);`. Same result is happening, I opened the file in VSCode and it told me the file was busy or locked.

Comment: For the original code, you need to call an overload of `File.Open()` that takes a `FileShare` parameter so you can specify that other processes/handles can read and/or write the file while you have it open.

Comment: @NathanChampion calling `StreamWriter.Flush()` after the foreach did not change anything.

@BACON I added `FileShare.Read` to the method, now I can view it while the application is running.

Comment: I would not call append all lines... just AppendAllText... because at the end AppendAllLines is doing the same as you... iterating over a stream...

Comment: Depending on what "after the foreach" means, I think you may have misapplied @NathanChampion's suggestion.  You need to call `Flush()` _inside_ the body of the `foreach` loop, after the call to `WriteLineAsync()` in order to see the write immediately.  If you called it _after_ (outside) the `foreach` loop, then that won't force the writes out until after some other thread calls `LogMessages.CompleteAdding()` and the enumerator is fully consumed by the `foreach`.  You might also try setting `sr.AutoFlush` to `true` instead of explicit calls to `Flush()`.

Answer (score -2):

You can run a separate task in which to synchronously write messages to a file:

```
    public async void RunTask()
    {
        await DoTask();
    }

    public Task DoTask()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(File.Open(DebugPath, FileMode.Append)))
            {
                foreach (var message in allMessages)
                {
                    sr.WriteLine(message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why are we doing this ? It sometimes (well all the time) best to explain your take on the problem and how this might help